# How to add a object into a JPanel

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, runnable

I am trying to add a ball into a JPanel, however, I am unsure how to do this Below is the code I currently have for adding  the ball into the JPanel. I am trying to add multiple balls in a random location onto the screen. The first appears as expected but any more than that don't appear on the screen.

Ball class;

```
public class Ball extends Component {

public static double ballX = rand.nextInt(500) + 40;
public static double ballY = rand.nextInt(300) + 10;
public static Ball[] balls = new Ball[20];

public Ball() {

}

public void draw(Graphics g2) {            
    Color color = new Color(r, g, b);
    g2.setColor(color);
    g2.fillOval((int) ballX, (int) ballY, 30, 30);
}
}
```

Method trying to add a ball into the JPanel;

```
public class BallFrames extends JFrame {

/* creates static varibles privite for use withing class and public for 
   use out side of the class */
public static final JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
public static final JPanel ballPanel = new JPanel();
public static JButton button;
public static JPanel displayPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
private static int FRAME_WIDTH = 600;
private static int FRAME_HEIGHT = 600;

/**
 * constructor called method to create the components
 */
public BallFrames() {
    setSize(FRAME_WIDTH,FRAME_HEIGHT);
    createComponents(); // creates all compononents
}

/*
* calls helper methods to create all of the componanats needed
 */
private void createComponents() {
    ActionListener listener = new BallListener(); 
    createPanel(); // creates a panel
    createButtons(listener); // Creates a button
    createSlider();
}

/**
 * method to create panels
 */
public void createPanel() {
    BallComponent component = new BallComponent(); // creates a new BallCompoenet
    displayPanel.add(component, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
    displayPanel.add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH); // adds thecontrol panel
    add(displayPanel); // adds the dice to the JFrame   
}

public static void addBall() throws InterruptedException {
   Ball.balls[BallListener.balls] = new Ball();
   System.out.println(BallListener.balls); // testing
   ballPanel.add(Ball.balls[BallListener.balls]);
   // ballPanel.add(ball);
    Runnable r = new BallRunnable();
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.start();
    t.join();
    ballPanel.repaint();
}
```

How I am drawing them;

```
public class BallComponent extends JComponent {

/**
 * calls paintComponenet to render images on the screen
 *
 * @param g
 */
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    int delay = 1000;
    super.paintComponent(g);        // call to super
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g; // recover the graphic     

    TimerListener listener = new TimerListener();
    Timer t = new Timer(delay, listener);     

    if (BallListener.gameOn == true) {
        for(int i = 0; i < BallListener.balls; i++){           
            Ball.balls[i].draw(g2);
        }

    BallFrames.displayPanel.repaint();
}
}

ActionListener for the buttons;

public class BallListener implements ActionListener {

public static boolean gameOn = false;
public static int balls = 0;

/**
 * gets the which button has been pressed and responds appriately
 *
 * @param event based on the event it will preform selected actions
 */
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    String action = event.getActionCommand();

    switch (action) {
        case "start":
            gameOn = true;

             {
                try {
                    BallFrames.addBall();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(BallListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                balls++;
            }
            BallFrames.displayPanel.repaint();
            break;
        case "pause":

            break;
    }
}
```

Ball Runnable;

```
public class BallRunnable implements Runnable {

private static Random rand = new Random();
public static boolean goLeft = true;
public static boolean goRight = false;
public static boolean goUp = false;
public static boolean goDown = false;
public static boolean diagonalUp = false;
public static boolean diagonalDown = false;
public static double speed = 0.2f;

public BallRunnable() {

}

public void run() {
    boundsCheckY1();
    boundsCheckX1();
    boundsCheckY2();
    boundsCheckX2();
}

public void boundsCheckX1() {
    int temp;

    if (Ball.ballX < 1) {
        temp = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;

       if(temp == 1) {
          goRight = true;
          goLeft = false;
          goUp = false;
          goDown = false;
          diagonalUp = false;
          diagonalDown = false;
       } else if (temp == 2) {
          goRight = true;
          goUp = true;
          goDown = false;
          goLeft = false;
          diagonalUp = false;
          diagonalDown = false;
       } else if (temp == 3) {
          goRight = true;
          goUp = false;
          goDown = true;
          goLeft = false;
          diagonalUp = false;
          diagonalDown = false;
       } else if (temp == 4) {
          goRight = true;
          goUp = false;
          goDown = false;
          goLeft = false;
          diagonalUp = true;
          diagonalDown = false;
       } else if (temp == 5) {
          goRight = true;
          goUp = false;
          goDown = false;
          goLeft = false;
          diagonalUp = false;
          diagonalDown = true;
       } 
    }
}

public void boundsCheckY1(){
    int temp;

    if (Ball.ballY < 1) {
       temp = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;

       if(temp == 1) {
          goRight = false;
          goLeft = false;
          goUp = false;
          goDown = true;
          diagonalUp = false;
          diagonalDown = false;
       } else if (temp == 2) {
          goRight = false;
          goUp = false;
          goDown = true;
          goLeft = true;
          diagonalUp = false;
          diagonalDown = false;
       } else if (temp == 3) {
          goRight = true;
          goUp = false;
          goDown = true;
          goLeft = false;
          diagonalUp = false;
          diagonalDown = false;
       } else if (temp == 4) {
          goRight = true;
          goUp = false;
          goDown = true;
          goLeft = false;
          diagonalUp = false;
          diagonalDown = true;
       } else if (temp == 5) {
          goRight = false;
          goUp = false;
          goDown = true;
          goLeft = true;
          diagonalUp = false;
          diagonalDown = true;
       }
    }
}

public void boundsCheckX2 () {
    int temp;

    if (Ball.ballX > 559) {
       temp = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;

      if(temp == 1) {
          goRight = false;
          goLeft = true;
          goUp = false;
          goDown = false;
          diagonalUp = false;
          diagonalDown = false;
       } else if (temp == 2) {
          goRight = false;
          goUp = true;
          goDown = false;
          goLeft = true;
          diagonalUp = false;
          diagonalDown = false;
       } else if (temp == 3) {
          goRight = false;
          goUp = false;
          goDown = true;
          goLeft = true;
          diagonalUp = false;
          diagonalDown = false;
       } else if (temp == 4) {
          goRight = false;
          goUp = false;
          goDown = false;
          goLeft = true;
          diagonalUp = true;
          diagonalDown = false;
       } else if (temp == 5) {
          goRight = false;
          goUp = false;
          goDown = false;
          goLeft = true;
          diagonalUp = false;
          diagonalDown = true;
       } 
    }
}

public void boundsCheckY2() {
    int temp;

     if (Ball.ballY > 470) {
       temp = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;

       if(temp == 1) {
          goRight = false;
          goLeft = false;
          goUp = true;
          goDown = false;
          diagonalUp = false;
          diagonalDown = false;
       } else if (temp == 2) {
          goRight = false;
          goUp = true;
          goDown = false;
          goLeft = true;
          diagonalUp = false;
          diagonalDown = false;
       } else if (temp == 3) {
          goRight = true;
          goUp = true;
          goDown = false;
          goLeft = false;
          diagonalUp = false;
          diagonalDown = false;
       } else if (temp == 4) {
          goRight = true;
          goUp = true;
          goDown = false;
          goLeft = false;
          diagonalUp = true;
          diagonalDown = false;
       } else if (temp == 5) {
          goRight = false;
          goUp = true;
          goDown = false;
          goLeft = true;
          diagonalUp = true;
          diagonalDown = false;
       }
    }
}
```

}

The viewer class;

```
public class BallViewer {

/**
 * creates the main frame
 *
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // If Nimbus is not available, you can set the GUI to another look and feel.
            }
            // new BallFrames().setVisible(true);
            JFrame frame = new BallFrames(); // creates new JFrame     
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setTitle("Multi-Treaded Balls");// Sets the Title       
            frame.setVisible(true); // Makes the frame visible
            frame.setResizable(false);
        }
    });
}
```

}

the timer listener;
    public class TimerListener implements ActionListener {

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    String action = event.getActionCommand();

    try {
        movement();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TimerListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
 public void movement() throws InterruptedException {
    if(goLeft == true) {       
        Ball.ballX -= speed;                     
    }
    if(goRight == true) {
        Ball.ballX += speed;           
    }
    if(goUp == true) {
        Ball.ballY -= speed;                         
    }
    if(goDown == true) {
        Ball.ballY += speed;            
    }
    if(diagonalUp == true) {
        Ball.ballY += speed / 2;              
    }
    if(diagonalDown == true) {
        Ball.ballY -= speed / 2;         
    }

}
```

}

I want to be able to add more than one ball on the screen at a given time, which also moves around like the first ball.

Comment: it does extend Component, ill add it in the code.

Comment: And what is the error that you get?

Comment: sorry that was just an old comment left in their isn't an error the balls don't seem to be added on to the screen after the first one.

Comment: I don't know why you bother to add them anyway, since you paint them directly from the `Balls.balls` array. It's really hard to know what your application does from the bits of code that you have given. Please create a [mcve] so we can run and see what you see.

Comment: I have updated my post and included all of my classes that I have created for this project.

Comment: Your x and y coordinates are static. That means that all balls go to the same location. Make them non-static and initialize the x and y in the constructor. You need to make a new random number every time you make a new ball, not just once when the class is loaded. That's what the constructor is for.

Comment: Thank you, Mad Physicist your comment fixed my issue. It was because the coordinates for the ball are static.

Comment: needed 15 rep first =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of the ball class is behaving as expected:

```
public class Ball extends Component {

public static double ballX = rand.nextInt(500) + 40;
public static double ballY = rand.nextInt(300) + 10;
public static Ball[] balls = new Ball[20];

public Ball() {

}

public void draw(Graphics g2) {            
    Color color = new Color(r, g, b);
    g2.setColor(color);
    g2.fillOval((int) ballX, (int) ballY, 30, 30);
}
}
```

All of the `static` fields are shared between all instances of the class. That's what `static` means. All `Ball`s have the same `ballX` and `ballY` coordinates.

What you are looking for is non-`static` fields that belong to each individual instance. You also have to initialize these fields every time you make a new ball. `static` fields only get initialized once when the class is loaded. There are a couple more changes that I would recommend:

- If your x- and y-coordinates belong only to the one ball, it is better to make them `private`.
- Extend `JComponent` instead of `Component`, since you are clearly using swing here.
- Implement `paintComponent` instead of `draw`. It will make your drawing code require less maintenance if nothing else.

Here is a version of the class that should work a bit better:

```
public class Ball extends JComponent
{

    private double ballX;
    private double ballY;
    public static Ball[] balls = new Ball[20];

    public Ball()
    {
        ballX = rand.nextInt(500) + 40;
        ballY = rand.nextInt(300) + 10;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g2)
    {
        Color color = new Color(r, g, b);
        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.fillOval((int) ballX, (int) ballY, 30, 30);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Painting code is for painting only.

You should NEVER create/start a Timer in a painting method. Get rid of all that code.

You should never invoke repaint(), this will cause an infinite loop.

Also, get rid of all you animation code. Your first task is to paint multiple balls on the panel. Once you get this working, then you worry about trying to do animation.

There is no need to extend JComponent, since you class is NOT a component. That is you never add the component to a panel. All you do is paint the object in another class.

So your `BallComponent` class (which is a component) needs to have an `ArrayList` which keeps track of the ball objects you want to paint.  So you need a method to add a ball object to this ArrayList. Then the `paintComponent()` method simply iterates through the list and paints all the balls.

Check out the `DrawOnComponent` example found in [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback camickr I have looked at your example, and agree with what you said I am looking and learning from the example you posted.